# search method in Stack class

Tags: java

I am using Stack class in Java. But the search method is not working..

Here is the code i am using with elements in temps array is `d b a g e c b`:

```
 int x=0,y=0;
 ss.setSize(50);
      ss.push(temps[x]);
      System.out.print(temps[x]);
      ss.push(1);
      System.out.println(" 1");
      for(x=1;x<z;x++){
          if((y=ss.search(temps[x]))>=0){
               System.out.println("Hi......from the search");
          }
        else{
        ss.push(temps[0]);
        System.out.print(temps[x]);
        ss.push(1);
        System.out.println(" 1");
       }
      }
```

Comment: What do you expect it to do, and what is going wrong?

Comment: What is the type of `temps[x]`?   Specifically, does it override `equals` to compare by other than identity?

Answer (score 2):

Step through your code and you'll notice the only items being put on the stack are 'd' and 1.  Also, the only items you are searching for are 'b', 'a', 'g', 'e', and 'c'.  So, search will always return -1.

In short, search is working fine and your code logic is not totally correct.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me you want a Stack that doesn't store duplicates.

There's one suspicious line:

```
else{
    ss.push(temps[0]);  // <--- this should be temps[x]
```

Answer (score 0):

The logic is wrong. It should be something similar to -

```
while length is 0 to temps_length-1 // length increments by 1 at each iteration

    variable returnValue Equals to stack.search(temps[length])

    if returnValue Equals To -1
       Add Element to the Stack if the stack is not full

    else
       Element found on the stack

    end if

End while
```